# Hooking virtual method on Win32 (return object larger than ptr crashes)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hook, calling-convention

So trying to hook a OpenVR method "ITrackedDeviceServerDriver::GetPose" but i'm getting access violations when my custom hooked method returns out (I think something is wrong with calling convention but idk enough about what x64 asm expects).

All other methods I hook in "ITrackedDeviceServerDriver" work fine. Only "GetPose" fails.

**Class thats being hooked looks like:**

```
class ITrackedDeviceServerDriver
{
public:
    virtual EVRInitError Activate( uint32_t unObjectId ) = 0;
    virtual void Deactivate() = 0;
    virtual void EnterStandby() = 0;
    virtual void *GetComponent( const char *pchComponentNameAndVersion ) = 0;
    virtual void DebugRequest( const char *pchRequest, char *pchResponseBuffer, uint32_t unResponseBufferSize ) = 0;
    virtual DriverPose_t GetPose() = 0;
};
```

**Object thats larger than ptr & gets returned from method that crashes**

```
struct DriverPose_t
{
    double poseTimeOffset;
    vr::HmdQuaternion_t qWorldFromDriverRotation;
    double vecWorldFromDriverTranslation[ 3 ];
    vr::HmdQuaternion_t qDriverFromHeadRotation;
    double vecDriverFromHeadTranslation[ 3 ];
    double vecPosition[ 3 ];
    double vecVelocity[ 3 ];
    double vecAcceleration[ 3 ];
    vr::HmdQuaternion_t qRotation;
    double vecAngularVelocity[ 3 ];
    double vecAngularAcceleration[ 3 ];
    ETrackingResult result;
    bool poseIsValid;
    bool willDriftInYaw;
    bool shouldApplyHeadModel;
    bool deviceIsConnected;
};
```

**Example of how I'm hooking the virtual methods:**

```
typedef DriverPose_t(__thiscall* GetPose_Org)(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr);
GetPose_Org GetPose_Ptr = nullptr;
DriverPose_t __fastcall GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr)
{
    DriverPose_t result = GetPose_Ptr(thisptr);// works
    //result.deviceIsConnected = true;
    return result;// after return I get access violation crash
}

void TestHook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver *pDriver)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    ZeroMemory(&mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    void** vTable = *(void***)(pDriver);
    VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)vTable, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &mbi.Protect);// unlock

    Activate_Ptr = (Activate_Org)vTable[0];
    vTable[0] = &Activate_Hook;// Hook!

    Deactivate_Ptr = (Deactivate_Org)vTable[1];
    vTable[1] = &Deactivate_Hook;// Hook!

    EnterStandby_Ptr = (EnterStandby_Org)vTable[2];
    vTable[2] = &EnterStandby_Hook;// Hook!

    GetPose_Ptr = (GetPose_Org)vTable[5];
    vTable[5] = &GetPose_Hook;// Hook!

    VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, mbi.Protect, &mbi.Protect);// lock
}
```

So why is "GetPose" the only method that fails after it returns out?
How can I fix the calling convention on "GetPose" to work with registers correctly?

Comment: `__thiscall` and `__fastcall` are not the same calling convention

Comment: in short, `void GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr, DriverPose_t*)` signature must be, you use  now by fact `void GetPose_Hook(DriverPose_t*, ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr)` - **order** of parameters is wrong. at all return object is wrong

Comment: @Remy I thought with x64 these calling conventions are all the same.

Comment: @ssbssa - almost, if not take in account implicit (hidden ) parameters. exist how minimum 2 case when implicit parameters used - for member functions (*this*) and when function try return object. if we have 2 implicit parameters - which will be first and which second ? return "object" (which can not be returned on platform) pure evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as already noted in comments

> `__thiscall` and `__fastcall` are not the same calling convention

even for *x64*. for *x86* this is obvious - `__thiscall` - pass first parameter (*this*) via *Ecx* register, and next parameters via stack (i skip now float/double parameters case). `__fastcall` - 1-first via *Ecx*, 2-second via *Edx*, and next via stack

in case *x64* (again let assume that no float/double parameters) - first 4 parameters via *Rcx, Rdx, R8, R9* and next in stack. so look like *x64* have single and common calling convention (no difference between *__stdcall, __fastcall, __cdecl, __thiscall*)

but exist question about **implicit** parameters. say in case *__thiscall* - the first parameter - *this* is **implicit** parameter, always passed as first parameter via *Ecx/Rcx*

and now case when function try "return" object. really on any platform function can return something only via cpu registers. it finite count, and only several of it can be used for return value store.

say on *x86(x64)* - for return value can be used: *AL, AX, EAX, RAX, DAX:EAX, RDX:RAX*
so function can return only something that have size - 1, 2, 4, 8 (and 16 for *x64*)

if function try "return" object with another size - this is impossible do direct, compiler need transform your code. for example if you write function:

```
DriverPose_t GetPose(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr)
{
    DriverPose_t pos = ...;
    return pos;
}
```

and call

```
DriverPose_t pos = GetPose(thisptr);
```

compiler (*of course this already implementation details, different compilers can do this in different ways !*) can transform this to

```
void GetPose(DriverPose_t *ppos, ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr)
{
    DriverPose_t pos = ...;
    *ppos = pos;
}
```

and call to

```
DriverPose_t pos;
GetPose(&pos, thisptr);
```

so here pointer to object passed to function as **first** ,hidden/implicit, parameter. but in case member function, still exist another hidden/implicit, parameter - *this*, which always passed as first, as result hidden/implicit, parameter for return value moved to **second** place !

```
struct ITrackedDeviceServerDriver
{
    DriverPose_t GetPose()
    {
        DriverPose_t pos = ...;
        return pos;
    }
};
```

and call

```
ITrackedDeviceServerDriver obj;
DriverPose_t pos = obj.GetPose();
```

*can be* transformed to

```
struct ITrackedDeviceServerDriver
{
    void GetPose(DriverPose_t *ppos)
    {
        DriverPose_t pos = ...;
        *ppos = pos;
    }
};
```

and call to

```
ITrackedDeviceServerDriver obj;

DriverPose_t pos;
obj.GetPose(&pos);
```

so real signature of function, if "uncover" *this* parameter is

```
void ITrackedDeviceServerDriver::GetPose(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* this, DriverPose_t *ppos)
{
    DriverPose_t pos = ...;
    *ppos = pos;
}
```

and call

```
ITrackedDeviceServerDriver obj;

DriverPose_t pos;
GetPose(&obj, &pos);
```

so compare

```
void ITrackedDeviceServerDriver::GetPose(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* this, DriverPose_t *ppos);
```

and

```
void GetPose(DriverPose_t *ppos, ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr);
```

---

you implement

```
DriverPose_t GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr);
```

which will be transformed by compiler to

```
void GetPose_Hook(DriverPose_t* ,ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr);
```

but really you need implement next hook:

```
void GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr, DriverPose_t* );
```

you confuse first and second parameters. however i think not need change object vtable at all, instead need return proxy object to client. possible and very generic implementation for *COM* interface hooks, but it too long for post here. for your case can be done next example of hook:

```
struct DriverPose_t 
{
    int x, y, z;
};

struct __declspec(novtable) IDemoInterface 
{
    virtual DriverPose_t GetPose() = 0;
    virtual ULONG GetComponent( const char * pchComponentNameAndVersion ) = 0;
    virtual void Delete() = 0;
};

class DemoObject : public IDemoInterface
{
    ULONG v;
    DriverPose_t pos;

    virtual DriverPose_t GetPose()
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
        return pos;
    }

    virtual ULONG GetComponent( const char * pchComponentNameAndVersion )
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%s)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, pchComponentNameAndVersion);
        return v;
    }

    virtual void Delete()
    {
        delete this;
    }

public:
    DemoObject(ULONG v, int x, int y, int z) : v(v) 
    { 
        pos.x = x, pos.y = y, pos.z = z; 
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

    virtual ~DemoObject()
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }
};

class Hook_DemoInterface : public IDemoInterface
{
    IDemoInterface* pItf;

    virtual DriverPose_t GetPose()
    {
        DriverPose_t pos = pItf->GetPose();
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>=<%d, %d, %d>\n", __FUNCTION__, this, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
        return pos;
    }

    virtual ULONG GetComponent( const char * pchComponentNameAndVersion )
    {
        ULONG v = pItf->GetComponent(pchComponentNameAndVersion);
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%s)=%u\n", __FUNCTION__, this, pchComponentNameAndVersion);
        return v;
    }

    virtual void Delete()
    {
        delete this;
    }
public:
    
    Hook_DemoInterface(IDemoInterface* pItf) : pItf(pItf) 
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

    ~Hook_DemoInterface() 
    { 
        pItf->Delete(); 
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }
};

BOOL CreateDemoIface(IDemoInterface** ppItf)
{
    if (DemoObject* pObj = new DemoObject (1, -1, 2, 3))
    {
        *ppItf = pObj;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL Hook_CreateDemoIface(IDemoInterface** ppItf)
{
    IDemoInterface* pItf;

    if (CreateDemoIface(&pItf))
    {
        if (Hook_DemoInterface* pObj = new Hook_DemoInterface(pItf))
        {
            *ppItf = pObj;
            return TRUE;
        }

        *ppItf = pItf;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

void UseIface(IDemoInterface* pItf)
{
    ULONG v = pItf->GetComponent("some string");
    DriverPose_t pos = pItf->GetPose();
    DbgPrint("v=%u, pos<%d, %d, %d>\n", v, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
}

void test()
{
    IDemoInterface* pItf;
    
    if (CreateDemoIface(&pItf))
    {
        UseIface(pItf);
        pItf->Delete();
    }

    if (Hook_CreateDemoIface(&pItf))
    {
        UseIface(pItf);
        pItf->Delete();
    }
}
```

instead hook object *vtable* - hook (if possible) object creation `CreateDemoIface` - replace it to self `Hook_CreateDemoIface` which return proxy object.

debug output

```
DemoObject::DemoObject<0000012C31E08F70>
DemoObject::GetComponent<0000012C31E08F70>(some string)
DemoObject::GetPose<0000012C31E08F70>
v=1, pos<-1, 2, 3>
DemoObject::~DemoObject<0000012C31E08F70>


DemoObject::DemoObject<0000012C31E08F70>
Hook_DemoInterface::Hook_DemoInterface<0000012C31DFAA10>
DemoObject::GetComponent<0000012C31E08F70>(some string)
Hook_DemoInterface::GetComponent<0000012C31DFAA10>(some string)=1
DemoObject::GetPose<0000012C31E08F70>
Hook_DemoInterface::GetPose<0000012C31DFAA10>=<-1, 2, 3>
v=1, pos<-1, 2, 3>
DemoObject::~DemoObject<0000012C31E08F70>
Hook_DemoInterface::~Hook_DemoInterface<0000012C31DFAA10>
```

Comment: I'm not creating the "ITrackedDeviceServerDriver" object. I'm trying to hook an already created object coming from an OpenVR driver.
I'm hooking an object being passed in from method: "TrackedDeviceAdded(IVRServerDriverHost* thisptr, const char *pchDeviceSerialNumber, ETrackedDeviceClass eDeviceClass, ITrackedDeviceServerDriver *pDriver)"

Comment: There is no way for me to change what "ITrackedDeviceServerDriver *pDriver" points to as shown in your example. I have to hook/modify the vTable for this to work.

Comment: @zezba9000 - i doubt that no way change pointer to object (need found where this object created and hook this). however i explain in all details why you got error and how fix it. even with hook vtable. you need use `void GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr, DriverPose_t*)` instead `DriverPose_t __fastcall GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr)`

Comment: @zezba9000 - want hook vtable - hook it. it is your choice. all what you need change in your current code - `DriverPose_t GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr)` to `void GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr, DriverPose_t *)`

Comment: That doesn't work with: "Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000018"
Its one of the first things I tried before asking the question.

This doesn't work: 
void GetPose_Hook(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver* thisptr, DriverPose_t* result)
{
*result = GetPose_Ptr(thisptr);
}

Comment: @zezba9000 - i not understand what is mean *That doesn't work with* - all what i wrote is absolute correct. are you not agree with this ? why you not use debugger for look where is more exactly error. which pointer is 0 ?

Comment: Ok so I needed to change func ptr typedef as well from "typedef DriverPose_t(__thiscall* GetPose_Org)(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver*);" to "typedef void(* GetPose_Org)(ITrackedDeviceServerDriver*, DriverPose_t*);" Now it works